# Como selecionar varios itens de um dropdown, escolher esses itens com um botão e depois recarregar a tela?

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, django

Nesse codigo html de um projeto Django como adicionar uma funcionalidade que o usuario ira escolher quantos serviços quer e clicar no botão quando terminar de escolher. Nesse aplicação so consigo escolher um serviço por vez, implementei o SELECT2, ja implementei a tag 'Multiple' mas não consigo escolher mais de 2 ou mais no dropdown, clico no servico e ja salva o 1º valor, os nomes com os serviços vem do Banco de Dados. Preciso selecionar os serviços que desejo e depois salvo-los em seguida, porque a consulta continua e vai para outro dropdown com veiculos do serviço que escolhi senão não funciona a pesquisa como um todo. Mas como fazer isso se quando seleciono 1 serviço a tela é recarregada por causa do evento onchange.

```html
HTML

<h3><strong>Serviço</strong></h3>

<select id="servico_cad" name="servico_cad" multiple="multiple" onchange="saveValue(this);this.form.submit();">

        {% for i in servico_cad %}
            
            <option value='{{i}}'>{{i}}</option>

        {% endfor %}
                        
            <option value='Todos'>Todos</option>
</select>
```

```js
JS
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#servico_cad").select2({
            closeOnSelect:false
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Você só recebe o último valor porque você está solicitando uma lista. No seu views, você deve utilizar request.GET.getlist('servico_cad') para poder manusear as duas opções escolhidas.

Comment: Entendi o seu comentario, no meu views.py o 'servico_cad' esta do tipo POST dentro de um if, pq essa opção do 'servico_cad' faz parte de uma pesquisa.